# How do I import JS file as text in React native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, import

In React Native we can inject JS into a WebView. The JS to be injected must be a String.

How can I create a separate JS file and import it as plain text so that I can inject it into the WebView?

Even better would be to be able to write TypeScript code and import it, but then it would need to be converted into JS.